# dynamic images in a swipe carousal

Tags: javascript

If I have a div class called 'header' and a div id called 'H1'

```
<div class="header" id="H1"><img src="_img/header/header.png" /></div>
```

how do I say "if class equals 'header' and id equals 'H1', then div id 'B1' should get its background image from id 'A1'" in javascript?  The background for 'A1' is identified in css.

```
<div id="B1"><img src="_img/hshots/hshot.png" /></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `id is equal to`

Comment: @SomeKittens good catch, that's wrong.  It should read...how do I say "if class equals 'header' and id equals 'H1', then div id 'B1' is to call id 'A1' for image. "

Comment: you want to change image onclick of div having class header and id H1 but what is "div id 'B1' is to call id 'A1' for image"?

Comment: @mkr9 I clarified once again.  I don't know if a swipe is recognized as click function.  Please help thanks.